# How do I increase the ulimit -n on 10.10.3

Tags: macos

There way on lion was this.From a previous post

```
echo 'kern.maxfiles=20480' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo -e 'limit maxfiles 8192 20480\nlimit maxproc 1000 2000' | sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf
echo 'ulimit -n 4096' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
```

but the first two files don't exist on Yosemite

Comment: See this page on [Unix StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188306/increasing-ulimit-u-settings-temporarily-in-osx-yosemite) for a possible answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes that answered it as well as this post on another site. http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X Now I just have to get Dovecot to recognise it. 
master: Warning: fd limit (ulimit -n) is lower than required under max. load (256 < 1000), because of default_client_limit

Answer (score 1):

Now it's easier with OSX 10.11.4 
sysctl.conf does now exist, or can be created if it doesn't.
First line above

```
echo 'kern.maxfiles=20480' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Second line above.Setting environment variables.
Can be set up ... [Use this link](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-mac-os-x-launchd-plist/). A short but useful how-to.

Third line above:
/etc/profile exists.

```
echo 'ulimit -n 4096' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
```